# coin.mx keeps giving me 403 forbidden error on my web request

Tags: c#, webrequest, bitcoin

I have been trying to make a query to the coin.mx site in a C# app, and I keep getting a 403 forbidden error.  Their example uses python:

```
base64.b64encode(str(HMAC(YOUR_SECRET, PATH+'?'+S, sha512).digest())),
```

where PATH is a http path (e.x. "/api/v2/trader/info")

given my secret is a hex string of the form "d1e2a3d4", I calculate my signature as follows:

```
HMACSHA512 mHasher512 = new HMACSHA512(secret);
var path = "/api/v2/trader/info?nonce=123"
var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( path );
var hash = mHasher512.ComputeHash(msg);
var hashb64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
return hashb64;
```

Does this seem right?

For reference: https://coin.mx/coinmx_api_en.pdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was having the same issue and found this question while searching for a solution. I finally fixed the problem by removing `?` in the path string. Try changing your path variable as follows (this is just for getting the hash string, the GET request still needs the `?` of course).

```
var path = "/api/v2/trader/infononce=123"
```

Note the documentation seems incorrect. I figured this out by looking at the sample python code.